# Isekai Manga where a bullied high school protagonist commits suicide, is transferred to a world where he finds a potion of god

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai

The story goes as: The protagonist is in high school and is thoroughly bullied. He decide to commit suicide and then the whole school or classroom gets transferred to a new world.

Later something happens and he gets send to a dungeon and there he finds treasure chest. He finds a potion of god (or something like that). He gets new power of decay or disintegrate and the other chest turns out to be a high level mimic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ***[Nito no Taidana Isekai Shoukougun: Saijaku Shoku "Healer" nano ni Saikyou wa Cheat desu ka?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/nito-no-taidana-isekai-shoukougun-saijaku-shoku-healer-nano-ni-saikyou-wa-cheat-desu-ka)*** (AKA *Nito's Lazy Foreign World Syndrome*).

> Hidako Masamune is a high school student who suffers from continuous bullying by his classmates. Becoming tired of it all, he decides to commit suicide, but instead he is transported to another world along with all his classmates. When they arrive, they find that they now possess amazing abilities but he was only granted the status of a "healer," the weakest skill of all. The king decides to get rid of him by transporting him to another far away place, but not before Hidako swears revenge against the king, the kingdom, and all of his classmates.

The MC is a high schooler who is driven to commit suicide as a result of being bullied by other students. After throwing himself off the roof of his school, he wakes up inside a medieval kingdom, alongside his classmates. Each of them has been granted a specific job and associated skill, his being 'healer.'

As his healer status is considered worthless, the MC is cast out into a dungeon, where he discovers three treasure chests. The first one he checks is empty. The second has a potion in it called the 'God of Revenge's Mischief' that reverses his healing power, enabling him to project 'Waves of Erosion.' The third is a mimic, a monster disguised as a treasure chest.

[image]

[image]